# Icon Looks Strange on iPhone Home Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, image

Please check the left and right hand corners, the icon looks nice in other situation, the original icon also look nice, but when it shows on the home screen of iphone, there is a black line around the corner as shown below:

[image]

[image: Retina]

[image: Non-Retina]

First one is original, second is retina, third is non-retina. 
What's wrong? How to fix this??
Thanks!!

Comment: Did you apply a rounded corner to the original icon? Show the original too.

Comment: Added original on the top. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [iOS HIGs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2) you shouldn't add a rounded corner to the icon you supply. The corners will be automatically rounded on the homescreen. You probably got the radius wrong by a pixel or two.

Comment: So what should I do now? Should I simply supply an icon without transparency for the four corners?? Just use a white background then. thanks!

Comment: That will probably just turn the black line into a white line. You should instead extend the green area out to the whole corner.

Comment: oh... so how about the other corners??

Comment: You should have no rounded corners at all. Check out the documentation I linked.

Comment: yes, I checked. How about the 512x512 and 1024x1024 icons? From the links, it seems I still need to supply rounded corners by myself??

Comment: You don't need to supply and icons with rounded corners. Neither in the app itself, nor when submitting through iTunes Connect. Apple handles that for you to have a consistent look across all app icons. The only situation where you ever need to do it yourself is if you want to create promotional materials or a website.

Comment: Thanks, I got it fixed. Now it looks very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Glow and shadow appears by default to all iOS homescreen icons. You can change it by adding:

> UIPrerenderedIcon YES

to your Plist file.

Comment: I don't think that's what he means, but the black line around the corner.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the template provided by this [link](http://www.pixelresort.com/blog/app-icon-template/) instead. There is a script inside this template that will automatically output all the necessary format needed for your app. Just provide a square image as the original image and the template will take care of automatically of applying a mask to the part you want to be rounded so you shouldn't face the issue you are observing here. As mentioned by DrummerB you shouldn't provide an icon image with rounded corner.

Comment: oh and the template allow you to visualize all the different formats at once :-)

Answer (score 0):

The way to fix this is copy your square retina icon, rename it to be the same name as your current non retina icon, open it with Preview, resize it by half, save, replace old rounded icon with the one you just made.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make icon image corners rounded, it gets rounded automatically.

Try without rounder corner image.